# npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin (over 30000ms)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

NPM version (npm -v) is 6.14.4

I want to create react application using 'npx create-react-app helloapp',but I got an error saying that it could not fetch the data.

Error is - npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2feslint-plugin (over 30000ms).

Comment: npm version issue.

Comment: To fix this issue, we can update npm version using below npm command.

npm install -g npm@latest.

Check your npm version, if your npm version is - 6.14.4 then update your npm version. 

**npm i -g npm@6.14.5**

It is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Clean npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then

```
npm install -g create-react-app    
npx create-react-app my-app     
cd my-app      
npm start
```

Comment: Issue is related to npm version. I update my npm version and it worked for me. npm i -g npm@latest

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
2. Edit the npmrc file and set:

   ```
    timeout:600000

    prefer-offline=true.
   ```
3. Try again. It will work.